# Tee-Object can't save output command comments to file

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have this code in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) and `Tee-Object` can't save all `Write-Host` command to file.txt. What I can do to repair this code?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web 
$users = Get-Content -Path 'G:\Shares\xx xxx\ResetPassword\UserList.txt'
ForEach ($user in $users) 
{
$unsecuredpwd = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10, 3)
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $unsecuredpwd -Force
Get-ADUser $user | Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $password -Reset
Get-ADUser $user | Set-AdUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
Enable-ADAccount -Identity $user
Write-Host “uzytkownik: $user”
Write-Host “haslo: $unsecuredpwd”
Write-Host “ `r`n`r`n”
} | Tee-Object -FilePath G:\Shares\xx xxx\ResetPassword\Output.txt
Read-Host -Prompt "click enter to exit"
```

Comment: What is your output/what tee-object writes to the file?

Comment: Tee-Object have to output username and generated password for each users

Answer (score 1):

`Write-Host` *doesn't send anything to the pipeline* so you should use something like `Write-Output` instead. Also there is a `Out-File` cmdlet which fits better then `Tee-Object` here since you only wan't so save the output to the file.

This is how you have to chnage your script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web 
Get-Content -Path 'G:\Shares\xx xxx\ResetPassword\UserList.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $user = $_
    $unsecuredpwd = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10, 3)
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $unsecuredpwd -Force
    Get-ADUser $user | Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $password -Reset
    Get-ADUser $user | Set-AdUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
    Enable-ADAccount -Identity $user
    Write-Output "uzytkownik: $user"
    Write-Output "haslo: $unsecuredpwd"
    Write-Output " `r`n`r`n"
} | Out-File -FilePath G:\Shares\xx xxx\ResetPassword\Output.txt
Read-Host -Prompt "click enter to exit"
```

Comment: Sorry mate :-). But I forgot to mention about point two with the foreach loop so your answer is probably better, thus upvoted

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems.

1. `Write-Host` doesn't write to the pipeline, it only shows on screen.
2. foreach (...) {} loops don't output to the pipeline either, so there would be nothing for `Tee-Object` to take as input.

Try using `ForEach-Object` and `Write-Object` instead:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web 
$users = Get-Content -Path 'G:\Shares\xx xxx\ResetPassword\UserList.txt'
$users | ForEach-Object {

    $user = $_

    $unsecuredpwd = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(10, 3)
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $unsecuredpwd -Force
    Get-ADUser $user | Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $password -Reset
    Get-ADUser $user | Set-AdUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
    Enable-ADAccount -Identity $user

    Write-Output “uzytkownik: $user”
    Write-Output “haslo: $unsecuredpwd”
    Write-Output “ `r`n`r`n”

} | Tee-Object -FilePath "G:\Shares\xx xxx\ResetPassword\Output.txt"
Read-Host -Prompt "click enter to exit"
```

Comment: Ok, but now I get error and in output file i don't see user name.
`Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is
null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command again.
At G:\Shares\xx xxx\ResetPassword\ResetPwd.ps1:16 char:16
+     Get-ADUser $user | Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $password -Reset
+                ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingV
   alidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Activ
   eDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser`